# Google analytics API feed

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-openid

I have been using a simple auth connect to retrieve analytics data from various profiles within my account using the main username and password as credentials. This has worked well until now and locally (on my MAMP server) the method still works. Even those accounts not using my main access details (as they are on another analytics account) these work fine live and locally. However, within the last 24hours my main account details on the live server seem to have stopped being able to retrieve data.

It authenticates fine but when I try and retrieve profile information I get the response:

```
<errors xmlns="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
  <error>
    <domain>GData</domain>
    <code>insufficientPermissions</code>
    <internalreason>User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.</internalreason>
  </error>
</errors>
```

Confusing as it works fine on my local, I have checked the API is enabled in the developers console.

Comment: I wouldn't bother fixing it I would switch to using a Service account.  Using your login and password is going to stop working very soon.

Comment: Which version of API are you using? I would also recommend service account and authentication via key file

Comment: Thanks, I have been using:
https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?ids=

Now using:
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/data?ids=

Do you know of any PHP examples using the technique above?